# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: согласование

Переводить ономатопею или нет, зависит от того, какие усилия предполагается затратить на ретушь, а также от жанра и целевой группы.

Comment: Я даже смысла предложения не поняла. При чём здесь перевод ономатопеи  (звукоподражаний) и ретушь? Что там ретушировать? Буквы?

Comment: Речь идет о комиксах. Иногда нужно переводить надписи, которые неотделимы от рисунка. Например, надпись на стене или заголовок газеты. Такие надписи необходимо ретушировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Знаки препинания расставлены верно.**

Общий смысл предложения не очень ясен, но структура понятна. **В препозиции находится изъяснительная часть сложного предложения**, которая отделяется **запятой или тире** (при выделении паузой).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

**Примет Дума этот закон или нет**, зависит от президента. **А вот сохранится это или нет**, зависит от нас. **Проявится она или нет**, зависит в том числе и от вашего образа жизни.

**Получится или нет** ― зависит от слаженных действий банковского сообщества, системы исполнительной власти, Центрального банка. **А уж останутся они в нашей сети или нет** ― зависит только от нас.